# ant task that requires user input?

Tags: ant, modal-dialog

I am accidentally running a task every once in a while by muscle memory and looking for a way to ensure I meant to run the task before running it.

Is there a way to popup up a modal dialog or require some sort of user validation before running an ant task?

Comment: user input in ant should be avoided... Perhaps you could have that target echo a "did you really really mean to do this?!" and wait for 10 seconds before continuing (giving you time to kill it).  that would save your team mates from the frustration of thinking it should be about done only to check and see it patiently waiting for input.

Comment: @thekkb you're right when it comes to ant scripts for automation, but jedierikb says he's "running a task.." which seems like a build script that has to be started intentionally. It's also possible to extend the ant core input task to continue after a configurable timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For core ant use the [input task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html), if you need a modal swing dialog use [Ant Forms](http://antforms.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Here follows an example, which asks to confirm a username.
You can select Yes, No or Cancel. If you select "No", then you will be asked to enter it.

This first target will call 2 other targets in order.

```
  <property name="username"         value="John"/>
  <property name="default_username" value="Paul"/>

  <target name="demo" description="confirm or enter a username."
          depends="confirm_username, ask_username" />
```

This is the one that opens the Yes/No/Cancel dialog.

```
  <target name="confirm_username" >
    <input message="Is your username [${username}] ?"
           validargs="Yes,Other,Cancel" addproperty="do.continue"/>

    <condition property="username" value="${username}">
      <equals arg1="Yes" arg2="${do.continue}"/>
    </condition>

    <condition property="result.other">
      <equals arg1="Other" arg2="${do.continue}"/>
    </condition>

    <fail message="Aborted." >
      <condition>
        <equals arg1="Cancel" arg2="${do.continue}"/>
      </condition>
    </fail>
  </target>
```

And this one asks for text input.

```
  <target name="ask_username" if="result.other">
    <input message="Give user name (defaults to [${default_username}])" 
           addproperty="username" 
           defaultvalue="${default_username}"/>
  </target>
```